# MongoDB - Only displaying data for selected information

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of data I wish to display, however I only need the specific records that have the type of data I want. I also want to display the remaining field details that only has that data. How do I approach this? This is what I currently have

`db.test.find({}, {Field: "info", _id: false})`

so far I can display the complete database however there are some blank fields that I do not require which is why I'm wondering what kind of alternative I should approach to display the remaining field data instead of using {} to display everything

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it something like this:

Lets say you want to search all the documents which has `Field : "info"` in it, and you only want `field1`, `field2`, and `field3` to come in the result docs, then you can query it something like this:

```
db.test.find({field : "info"},{ field1:1,field2:1,field3:1,_id:0})
```

Here, First parameter of `find` query : `{ field:"info"}` , is used to match the required/selected documents. and 2nd parameter : `{ field1:1,field2:1,field3:1,_id:0}` is used to include only those fields in the result.

Add all those fields you want in the second parameter like below:

```
field4:1,
field5:1,
...
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I just tried it and I can no longer fetch any records for some reason.

Comment: What i gave you was a Pseudo code, you need to enter the names of actual fields which are there in your collection. Can you show me your collection schema, so that i can help you better?

Comment: yes I actually swapped the fields with my own field names